# File version with VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, version

In the past I used a resource editor in VS applications to add a version number (`VS_VERSION_INFO`) to my program that is visible in the file properties window!

[image]

Since this feature needs MFC (`afxres.h`) I want to get rid of it:

How can I achieve same or similar results, or what is the suggested way in VS2017 C++ projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think afxres.h is necessary, I have resource scripts with version resources that rely only on winres.h